# CheckBox Field does not show checked or not in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

i'm used checkbox field in gridview to show bit value from database on my gridview
i used default editing row on gridview , when i update row (checked checkbox field) 
in database update successfully but in gridview does not show checked or not checked
when i refresh page not show again or when i rerun page same problem as a whole does not show checkbox field bit value status check box filed always is empty and not checkedthis is my gridview html codes

```
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldsReplys" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' UpdateCommand="MNG_Forum_Update_Reply_Status" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="MNG_Forum_Select_Replys" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                        <UpdateParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int64" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="PostStatus" Type="Int32" />
                        </UpdateParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    <asp:GridView ID="grdReplys" runat="server" CssClass="GridViewStyle" DataKeyNames="id" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" Width="100%" DataSourceID="sqldsReplys">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ButtonType="Image" SelectImageUrl="~/cpanel/assets/img/sel.png">                                        
                            </asp:CommandField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ردیف" ReadOnly="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ptitle" HeaderText="عنوان مطلب" ReadOnly="true" />
                            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="PostStatus" HeaderText="وضعیت نمایش" />
                            <asp:TemplateField>                    
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="delete" ToolTip="حذف این رکورد" 
                                    OnClientClick="return confirm('آیا مطمئن هستید؟')" ImageUrl="~/cpanel/assets/img/Trash.png" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:CommandField  ShowEditButton="True" EditText="ویرایش" UpdateText="تائید" CancelText="لغو" />
                        </Columns>
                        <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
                        <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyRowStyle" />
                        <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
                        <EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowStyle" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowStyle" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: show me your Page Load code means aspx.cs page code..

Comment: i dont write any codes on page load i think is not need

Comment: ok you are binding your grid through sqldatasource.your grid refresh or bind the others fields except checkbox or not

Comment: @Arun he is using SqlDataSource that will manage all postback by itself..if he writes his code manually means from page_load then PostBack will come into act..

Comment: @Net Projects Ir plz check your data query by which you are binding your grid. May be you forget to add `PostStatus` column in your select query.\

Comment: my select query is like "select * from tblname" is think "*" will select every fields in table

Comment: my problem is checkboxfield does not show filed status (is checked or not) it show me empty checkbox always while field is true or "1" values

Comment: yes it will select all columns..try to use checkbox inside template field